# CSS site how to

Tags: html, css

Someone who can provide me good links to make a site like that.. I mean the design are really amazing, and i want to do something new and more professional, than just design in photoshop then make a frame and voila..

`http://fusionmedia.dk/` `http://tjenonline.dk/`

again, i want to learn how to do like that site, the menubar and whole design is big and comfortable with all screen solution .. i believe its CSS and HTML normal (when i press view source, its like that)

Comment: You should ask this on doctype.com.

Comment: @Felix. In general I think Doctype is a waste, but this is the exact questions that belong here. Ones not about fixing some small CSS bug or the How-To, but rather the Design part of it.. Shame there isn't yet a close reason for "belongs on Doctype"

Answer (score 5):

You could start by learning CSS. [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is great for folks just learning the basics. Once you learn the basics, you have a foundation, which like so many other things, makes advanced topics easier.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the advice above. Or learn [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and analyze the pages, both use JQuery to provide the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting started by getting the firefox add-on "Firebug". Once you have this, you can go to the site and start looking at the structure of the web site. With Firebug, you can right click anything on the webpage, then click "Inspect Element" and it will show you how it is composed.

You are right that CSS is key for "Designing" a site. Unfortunately we can't just inject you with all the knowledge you need to build a site like that. Try to get started, and come back when you get stuck, your question will be more well received then...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are still using the "slice and dice" method ( design in some graphics program, then shove everything in a table or frameset ) and want to learn to make sites the modern way. Then you want to learn about web standards (xhtml & css), unobtrusive javascript, and ajax.